# passing argument to generators, vo

Tags: javascript, generator, nightmare

I'm trying to scrape an entire page using nightmare js and return the result to the calling function. In order to do so, by extending the nightmare example, I pass an argument to a generator function. For a reason I don't understand, the run() function never gets called.

Thanks for your help.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');
const fs = require('fs');

url = "http://google.com";

vo( run(url) )(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("end result length: ", result.length);

    fs.writeFile("test.html", result, function(err) {
        if(err) { return console.log(err); } })

 });

function *run(url) {
    console.trace()
    var x = Date.now();
    var nightmare = Nightmare();
    var html = yield nightmare
      .goto(url) // 'http://google.com')
      .evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
      });

   console.log("done in " + (Date.now()-x) + "ms");
    console.log("result:", html.length);

    yield nightmare.end();
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Easy answer: change the line "vo( run(url) )(function(err, result) {} )" to  "vo( run )(url, function(err, result) {} )"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just wrong terminology in the example above. This is how vo works:

```
vo( run )(url1, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("end result length: ", result.length);

    fs.writeFile("test.html", result, function(err) {
        if(err) { return console.log(err); } })

 });
```